# How to make 2 HTTP requests asynchronously using modern Java 8 features?

Tags: java, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, completable-future

I'm coming from the JS world and trying to understand how asynchronous programming works in modern Java. I read that the most recent big updates in this topic were made in Java 8 where they introduced the [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) class but it seems a little complicated and I thought that it will be easier to understand if I have some parallels with something that I already know.

In modern Node.js in order to execute 2 functions with asynchronous calls (IO, network etc) asynchronously I would write `Promise.all(function1(), function2())`.

Let's say I want to make 3 HTTP Get requests asynchronously, get the result of execution and use it in some function called `consumeResults()`. Here's how I'd do it in Node.js

```js
async function executeAndDoSomethingWithResults() {
   const request1 = httpGetRequest("url1")
   const request2 = httpGetRequest("url2")
   const request3 = httpGetRequest("url3")
   const results = await Promise.all([request1, request2, request3])
   consumeResults(results)
}

async function httpGetRequest(url) {
   // blablabla
   // wrap the native http module to return a Promise
}
```

What would be an alternative to this piece of code in Java 8+?

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Comment: I never said it is. But asynchronous programming is asynchronous programming. Different methods but similar concepts.

Comment: In Java, you probably want [HttpClient.sendAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#sendAsync(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)).  But it’s not available in versions of Java older than 11.

Comment: @VGR nice! That would get rid of the wrapping method. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can do it like to mimic the same behaviour and design

```
void executeAndDoSomethingWithResults() {

    CompletableFuture<SomeClass> request1 = httpGetRequest("url1");
    CompletableFuture<SomeClass> request2 = httpGetRequest("url2");
    CompletableFuture<SomeClass> request3 = httpGetRequest("url3");

    CompletableFuture.allOf(request1, request2, request3)
                        .thenApply(ignore -> 
                          consumeResults(request1.join(), request2.join(), request3.join())
                        );
}

CompletableFuture<SomeClass> httpGetRequest(final String url) {
    // blablabla
}
```

The code can be optimized more.

Comment: Wouldn't `request1.join()`, `request2.join()` and `request3.join()` execute synchronously here then?

Comment: ok, after staring at Javadocs for 5 minutes I understood that `allOf` will guarantee that the Futures are completed. And `.join()` is just an artifact. At that point the future is already completed and the result is available.

Comment: You wrote that you mimicked the design. How would you execute that behavior with a proper "Java design"?